# how to update ui:repeat and still component id

Tags: jsf

i want to duplicate form, my code:

```
<p:outputPanel id="idUpdate">
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
  <o:form id="formId-#{item.id}">
     <p:inputText id="txtSearch-#{item.id}"/>
     ....
  </o:form>
</ui:repeat>
</p:outputPanel>

<o:form id="formHandle">
  <p:commandButton value="Add Form" actionListener="#{bean.cloneForm}" update="idUpdate">
</o:form>
```

when i click `Add Form`, form was added, but in browser, id of form not as I expected.

```
...
<form id="j_idt295:1:formId-">
```

i need get id of form for handle javascript (hidden or show).
I have reference: 
[How to update  data without page reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804281/how-to-update-uirepeat-data-without-page-reload)
,[How to create dynamic JSF form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510614/how-to-create-dynamic-jsf-form-fields)

how to get it. thanks

Comment: example,in home page i have 20 chart, i want onclick each chart will show form search and datatable of that chart into menu-tab. i need get all id of form for hidden them, then only show menu-tab with form and datatable corresponding

Comment: I also need get id of `p:datatable` for update when click button `SEACH`

Comment: There no `p:dataTable` in your code...

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks, i'm understand. i fixed

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147771

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes, you might not need that many forms...

Comment: @JasperdeVries i need many form to save status,value or anything of form and data of datatable for each chart when menu-tab change. thanks

Comment: You don't NEED multiple forms to do so, but you could. This all looks like an XY problem to me.